# no puedo realizar operaciones con resultado decimal

Tags: python

[image: intento poner 7/2]

intento poner 7/2 
y sale 3 en vez de 3.5 
al igual que si pongo
x = 7/2
x me lo arroja como 3 y si uso type(x) me arroja la variable como int

Answer (score 2):

Ese comportamiento es típico en python2. En python 3 sí que funciona como esperas y `7/2` te sale 3.5.

Cámbiate a python3 si te es posible (python 2 dejará de ser soportado a finales de 2019).

Si no te es posible, puedes usar como "apaño" lo siguiente al inicio de tu código:

```
from __future__ import division
```